# Cyclic garbage collection for a concurrent queue (Python C extension)

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, garbage-collection, python-c-api

I am trying to wrap a concurrent queue implementation in C with Python. It has two methods:

- `push` adds a generic void pointer (in this case a `PyObject` pointer) to an internal linked list and increments its reference count by one.
- `pop` removes an object pointer from the linked list and returns it.

In the internal linked list each node holds a pointer to the stored object, and a pointer to the next node. Each operation activates one of two mutexes to prevent race conditions (if you are curious, it is a [Michael-Scott two-lock concurrent queue](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/%7Escott/papers/1996_PODC_queues.pdf)). As I mentioned, I want to use this queue to store Python objects.

Reading the official Python documentation I came upon [cyclic garbage collection](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/gcsupport.html#supporting-cycle-detection), which is enabled with the `Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_GC` flag. From what I understand, any Python type that is a container for other types (including other containers as well) must support it, and my queue seems to fall into this category. Any type that supports this functionality must define the `tp_traverse` and `tp_clear` fields in their type struct with their own implementations. For a normal container type ([like a list](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/listobject.c#l2220)), the `tp_traverse` function would loop over all the contained elements and call `Py_VISIT` on them. `tp_clear` is similar, but it calls `Py_XDECREF`.

My questions:

- Should I lock the whole list before looping through all of its elements to perform de adequate calls? Does this lock impact performance or are threads suspended anyway when garbage collection is performed?
- Should I remove an element from the queue completely after calling `Py_XDECREF`? My guess is that I should check if the `ob_refcnt` field is zero for each `PyObject` in my queue, is this correct?